# Do I have to start Elastic search?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

If Elastic Search is always running on port:9200, do I have to start it each time I use it?

I am using Linux, MAC and Windows, in a nut shell I run command "bin/elastic" or another variation based on OS commands and it usually "starts" Elastic Search.

I just want to know why its always running on port:9200 and if I need too start Elastic each time I boot up a Operation System.

Answer (score 2):

you download elasticsearch.zip and unzip it and run with "bin/elasticsearch"

you can download deb (for Debian or Ubuntu Linux) or rpm (for redhat or centos) version and install it as service for example in centos:

```
sudo wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.0.0.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh elasticsearch-6.0.0.rpm
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service 
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service // for running after boot
```

if you want to change the default port of elastic you must edit the elasticsearch.yml file. you can find this file in the manual running in config/elasticsearch.yml and in installation as service in centos in the /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

you can uncomment this line:

```
#http.port: 9200
```

and change port for example:

```
http.port: 9900
```